# How do I make my class attribute not be able to access instance variable directly?

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

How can I make my code work so that the balance attribute doesn't access the instance variable(I believe it's @balance) directly? Can someone explain what it means for an attribute to *access* an instance variable?

I'm new to using Ruby and just got into learning about Ruby classes. In this chapter, my objectives is to understand the concept of instance variables, demonstrate the us of getter and setter methods, understand how to use instance methods, and understand the concept of encapsulation.

```
class BankAccount
  attr_accessor :balance

  def initialize(balance)
    @balance = balance
  end

  def withdraw(amount)
    if (balance >= amount)
      @balance = balance - amount
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Just remove the `attr_accessor` and add your version of `balance` method.

Comment: BTW, from your code it's not obvious __at all__, why you'd want `balance` to not read `@balance`.

Comment: You distinguish "balance attribute" from "balance instance variable" and that part is confusing. Clarification question: Are you programming with Rails, and is the "balance attribute" a column in a database table? Otherwise, like @SergioTulentsev pointed out, it's not obvious why you want there to be a distinction. The getter and setter methods created by `attr_accessor :balance` are SUPPOSED to get and set the instance variable (which is @balance).

Comment: I was given instructions to make sure that the class attribute is not "directly" accessing the instance variable. I'm only using Ruby at the moment.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev isn't the `attr_accessor` needed for all attributes? From what I've read, all attributes must have a getter and setter method. What would adding a `balance` method do?

Comment: @tableguarder: is it not your requirement to add a "less direct" getter than that from attr_accessor? If so, remove attr_accessor and add your less direct version.

Comment: @tableguarder and JFYI, you have defined a setter, but you don't use it (you instead set `@balance` variable directly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby `attr_reader :balance` is more or less just a convenience version of the following method:

```
def balance
  @balance
end
```

Similarly, `attr_writer :balance` is just a short form for

```
def balance=(value)
  @balance = value
end
```

And `attr_accessor :balance` is short for `attr_reader :balance` plus `attr_writer :balance`.

So as you can see `attr_reader` *accessing* the instance variable is nothing special, e.g. in your code you also access the instance variable in `#initalize` and `#withdraw`.

You need to clarify why you wouldn't want to access it directly. And what that even means. Because you can either access the instance variable using `@balance` or not, there is no *indirect* in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Define your own version of `balance` reader method:

```
class BankAccount
  attr_accessor :balance

  def initialize(balance)
    @balance = balance
  end

  def withdraw(amount)
    if (balance >= amount)
      @balance = balance - amount
    end
  end

  def balance
    'balance from method directly'
  end
end
```

Now when you call `balance` method, it'd read your defined one and return value accordingly.